# Joint normality of RV made up of jointly normal RVs

Tags: probability, linear-model, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm reading a paper where (simplifying):

$Y_{i} = \beta_\theta \theta_i + \beta_x X_i + \epsilon_i $,

$\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma_\epsilon^2) \perp (\theta_i, X_i) $, and $\beta_\theta$ and $\beta_x$ are fixed constants, and $\theta_i$ and $X_i$ are jointly normally distributed such that:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\theta_i \\
X_i
\end{pmatrix}
\sim N \left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{\theta} \\
\mu_{x}
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{\theta}^2 & \rho \sigma_{\theta} \sigma_{x} \\
\rho \sigma_{\theta} \sigma_{x} & \sigma_{x}^2
\end{pmatrix}
\right) $.

In a proof, the authors refer to the multivariate Gaussian of $(\theta_i, X_i, Y_i)$.

**My question**: How do the authors know that the *joint* distribution of $(\theta_i, X_i, Y_i)$ is Normal?

I (think) I understand why the distribution of $Y_i$ is univariate normal: it's the sum of jointly normal variables ($\theta_i$ and $X_i$) and an independent normally distributed variable ($\epsilon_i$). Right?

But what are the characteristics of this case which make $Y_i$ *jointly* normal with $\theta_i$ and $X_i$?

Context: I'm more of an *applied* econometrics person, so I know some basic probability stuff but have forgotten a lot of it (clearly).

Comment: Just thinking: is it because any linear combination of $Y_i$ and $\theta_i$ and $X_i$ reduces to a linear combination of $\theta_i$ and $X_i$ and $\epsilon_i$, and we know that this linear combination will be normally distributed for the reason I outline in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the properties of multivariate normal vectors.

Since $(\theta, X)$ are jointly normal and $\epsilon$ is normal independent of them, wouldn't you say that $(\theta, X, \epsilon)$ is jointly normal as well. (Exercise: Find the mean and covariance matrix)

The (random) vector $$(\theta, X, Y)=(\theta, X, \beta_\theta \theta + \beta_X X + \epsilon) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\\beta_\theta&\beta_X&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\theta\\X\\\epsilon\end{pmatrix}$$

Call the matrix in front "A". From the properties of MVRNM's, we have $A\mu=\mathcal N(A\mu_0,A\Sigma_0A^T)$ if $\mu\sim \mathcal N(\mu_0, \Sigma_0)$. We can clearly see that the random vector a few lines prior is multivariate normal as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is the intuition that if $(\theta, X, \epsilon)$ is jointly normal, then by definition a linear combination of $(\theta, X, \epsilon)$ (here via the matrix $A$) must also be jointly normal?

Comment: @galelamanzi that is correct.

Comment: thanks! very helpful.